# How many numbers $n < 100$ are not divisible by a square of any integer greater than $1$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many numbers $n < 100$ are not divisible by a square of any integer
>   greater than $1$?

Working through the above counting problem. I got $48$ using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, do you agree?

Comment: $1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,13,14,15,17,19,21,22,23,26,29,30,31,33,34,35,37,38,$ $39,41,42,43,46,47,51,53,55,57,58,59,61,62,65,66,67,69,70,71,73,74,77,$ $78,79,82,83,85,86,87,89,91,93,94,95,97$.

Comment: Try using erastothenes sieve, but instead of cancelling as multiples of prime numbers, cancel out multiples of squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the inclusion-exclusion principle gives you
$$
N_{n}=n-\sum_{p}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\sum_{p < q}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2 q^2}\right\rfloor-\sum_{p<q<r}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2 q^2 r^2}\right\rfloor + \ldots,
$$
for the count $\le n$, where the sums are over all primes.  In this case the non-zero terms are:
$$
N_{99}=99-\left(\left\lfloor\frac{99}{2^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{99}{3^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{99}{5^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{99}{7^2}\right\rfloor\right) + \left\lfloor\frac{99}{2^2 3^2}\right\rfloor \\=99-(24+11+3+2)+2=99-40+2\\=61.
$$

Comment: Just a quick note, something I found useful for anyone attempting this question in the future: First calculate how many 'prime squares' (that is squares that cannot be formed by multiplying together two smaller squares) are divisible 99 using inclusion-exclusion, then subtract this number from 99 to obtain how many are not divisible.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how you got to $48$.

I assume we're working in the natural numbers so $99$ numbers less than $100$ all together. Any number divisible by a square number $>1$ is divisible by a prime square.

- $24$ are divisible by $4$.
- $11$ are divisible by $9$ - two of which ($36$ and $72$) are already counted above.
- $3$ are divisible by $25$,
- $2$ are divisible by $49$

Total of $24+(11-2)+3+2=38$ are divisible by squares $>1$, so $61$ numbers $<100$  are not divisible by a square number $>1$.

Comment: Joffan, both 49 and 98 are less than 100 and divisible by 49. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm still half-asleep. Careless of me - but accidentally a good demonstration of why setting out your working is important :-)

Comment: Given the two numbers you initially overlooked, there are $24 + 11 + 3 + 2 = 40$ numbers less than $100$ that are divisible by a perfect square, so you need to adjust your final answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, no, the total is correct. The 2 missing are 36 and 72 which have been double-counted by 4 and 9. Clarified the addition